# get rid of choppiness when doing global regex replacement

Tags: javascript

Let's pretend that we have a page, say:

```
<html>
  <body>
    (111) 111.1111
    <br />
    (222) 222.2222
    <br />
    333 333 3333
    <br />
    444-444-4444

    <script>
      // replace all phone numbers with our own

      var re = /\d{3}[().-\s[\]]*\d{3}[().-\s[\]]*\d{4}/g;
      var sourcestring = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
      var replacementpattern = "(111) 867-5309";
      var result = sourcestring.replace(re, replacementpattern);
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = result; 
   </script>                       
  </body>
```

Our page loads normally but it shows the original phone numbers for maybe 1/4 of a second (highly noticeable).

Is there a way to essentially stop the displaying of other numbers and JUST display the (111) 867-5309 string when replaced?

Maybe a solution is to have something to either parse the html as it comes in (but before it displays)?

EDIT:

Just for clarification, I would not have access to the the rest of the HTML other than the javascript (which would be loaded in via src=)

Comment: I would wrap the numbers in a hidden element and then show that element once the replacement is finished. So instead of `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, target that specific element by ID and replace its contents.

Comment: I should edit the question because I don't have access to the page other than the javascript.  The script itself is hosted on my servers and it's placed on clients' webpage.  I therefore don't have access to the html unfortunately

Comment: Surely there's an element that wraps everything you want to replace (all the phone numbers). Even if there isn't, you can set the body to `display:none;` before replacing and remove that when you're done.

Comment: As long as the script is included at the end of the body, there's **nothing** you can do.  Your script isn't even parsed until those phone numbers have already been rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the page enough to move your script, you can make it work.

1. First, put your script before the content (in the head, preferably).
2. Your code should be in a function that you can call *after* the content is ready.
3. Handle the DOMContentLoaded event with your function. ([reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded), with list of fallbacks if it isn't supported by your browser)

Something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function replacePhoneNumbers () {
          // replace all phone numbers with our own

          var re = /\d{3}[().-\s[\]]*\d{3}[().-\s[\]]*\d{4}/g;
          var sourcestring = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
          var replacementpattern = "(111) 867-5309";
          var result = sourcestring.replace(re, replacementpattern);
          document.documentElement.innerHTML = result;
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', replacePhoneNumbers);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

If you can't move your script, then there's nothing you can do; it won't be executed until the content is already rendered.

Comment: You're a wizard, Andrew.  Out of curiosity, do you know what browsers support this?  I just tested on osx chrome, firefox, safari and it works but I'm on the latest versions.  Do you know about i.e.?

Comment: MDN says IE9+ supports it.  It also lists fallbacks.  I will add a link in the answer.